# How to write cURL requests to wso2

Tags: curl, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to connect to wso2 API which i created using REST.

```
$userData = array("username" => "user", "password" => "password");
$ch = curl_init("http://wso2.endpoint.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer concernPart", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

**Now i am not sure how to write the `"Authorization: Bearer concernPart"`. Do i need to add this statically in each request?
How do i change this in all my requests if i change the `Bearer token` or regenerate it.**

**Or there is a way i can hit wso2 and get the `Bearer token` and use it in my requests.**

Comment: Are you looking for this guide? https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is call the token endpoint using preferred grant type and get a new access_token. Then you can use that access token with your actual API call.
Refer [WSO2 Doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Token+API) on how to obtain an access token